# password protecting ASPX file from within the file itself (without touching web.config)

Tags: c#, asp.net

i work as a pen-tester for a security company.

as a part of our PT, if we are successful we sometimes upload a reverse shell ASPX file, i cannot share that here for obvious reason but we would like to password protect the file.

our programmers tried doing that but they don't know how, only via the web.config file (which even if we gain access to, won't modify)

the reason we need to do this is because when we upload the file, its a risk because if an actual malicious user finds the shell.aspx file he has control of the system, we want to mitigate that risk.

so is there any way to password protect a specific ASPX file?

ty.

Comment: what kind of password protection? windows authentication?

Comment: Do you mean password protect from being downloaded and opened locally within the web server? I don't think that's possible since ASPX is just a text file. If you encrypted it then IIS would just have to unencrypt it somehow and the decryption key would need to be on the server anyway.

Comment: ill be more accurate with the issue: If i upload a file called shell.aspx(the actual name is much longer) as a test and a proof of concept to a vulnerability and exploitation to show to the company, and an actual real attack accidental finds the file on the site application, he immidietly has control over the server and can send commands, upload his own shell for later use and even delete the whole thing. so ANY password protection would be fine, i just want to minimize the risk factors.

Answer (score 0):

(Posted as an answer pending enough rep to comment)

I assume your shell.aspx, when run, presents the user with a form containing an input serving as a command prompt, and that you'd like this functionality to be available for demonstration purposes but not for drive-by attackers who stumble on the page's URL.

What I would do is modify the page so that it also prompts for a (strong) password. Presumably the page server-side code-behind logic is within the same file - you will have to hardcode the password's once-way cryptographic hash and only execute the user command if the password's hash matches the hardcoded value.